# "go build" does not generate file in golang

Tags: go

I used `go build` to generate files. But I can only generate `main`, which mean `go build main.go` works while `go build dao.go` does not generate anything?

How can I generate `dao`?

Comment: What are your trying to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From `go help build`:

```
When the command line specifies a single main package,
build writes the resulting executable to output.
Otherwise build compiles the packages but discards the results,
serving only as a check that the packages can be built.
```